# Rails link from one model to another based on db field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, hyperlink

I have a company model and a person model with the following relationships:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kases
  has_many :people
  def to_s; companyname; end
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kases # foreign key in join table
  belongs_to :company
end
```

In the create action for the person, I have a select box with a list of the companies, which assigns a company_id to that person's record:

```
<%= f.select :company_id, Company.all.collect {|m| [m.companyname, m.id]} %>
```

In the show view for the person I can list the company name as follows:

```
<%=h @person.company.companyname %>
```

What I am trying to work out, is how do I make that a link to the company record?

I have tried:

```
<%= link_to @person.company.companyname %>
```

but that just outputs the company name inside a href tag but links to the current page.

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need pass in second argument the path where you want go

```
<%= link_to @person.company.companyname, @person.company %>
```

or with the full version :

```
<%= link_to @person.company.companyname, company_url(@person.company) %>
```

Comment: Great, I knew I must have been missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, `link_to` cannot guess where you want it to lead to, if you give it only the text of the link :)

In order to have the link lead to the company page, you need to add a path:

```
<%= link_to @person.company.companyname, company_path(@person.company) %>
```

This assumes you have proper restful routes for your company

```
map.resources :companies
```

and the page you're heading to is `companies/show.html.erb`.

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth response, I have managed to get this working.